# When can "creating" and "declaring" be used synonymously?

Tags: language-agnostic

Once in a while you stumble over a technical article where "creating" and "declaring" are used synonymously.

E.g.

> declares an array of ints
>
> creates an array of ints

But aren't declaring and creating two different things? Or does it depend on the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C and C++, the creation of an object also declares it:

```
int main() {
    int a[10];   // create a
    a[3] = 42;   // use a - no need for a separate declaration
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The two are clearly separate, at least under some circumstances. Just for example, in C or C++, there are declarations that just declare things, and there are definitions that both declare *and* create them, and (only in C++) there are `new` expressions that create objects without declaring them (and, arguably, a malloc sort of does the same in C).

Likewise, in a language that supports lambda expressions, creation and declaration are separate -- a lambda expression creates something (e.g., a function) but doesn't (by itself) declare it (bind a name to it).